# Can this be refactored into nicey nice LINQ?

Tags: linq, refactoring

I have an IList of type Breadcrumb which is just a lightweight class that has NavigationTitle, NavigationUrl and IsCurrent properties. It is cached on the webserver. I have a method that builds out the current breadcrumb trail up until the first Breadcrumb that has IsCurrent set to true... using the code below. Its very ugly and definitely a quick dirtbag willie solution, but I was curious, can this be easily refactored into LINQ?

```
IList<Breadcrumb> crumbs = new List<Breadcrumb>();
bool foundCurrent = false;
for (int a = 0; a < cachedCrumbs.Count; a++)
{
    crumbs.Add(crumbs[a]);
    if (foundCurrent)
    {
      break;
    }
    foundCurrent = (crumbs[a + 1] != null && ((Breadcrumb)crumbs[a + 1]).IsCurrent);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm typing this as I think, so that it shows a train of thought as well as just an answer.

- Your source is just cachedCrumbs
- You want to add the first crumb which *does* have IsCurrent set, but nothing afterwards
- TakeWhile sounds like the way to go, but getting the "previous value had IsCurrent" is a bit of a pain
- We can use a closure to effectively keep a variable determining whether the last value had IsCurrent set
- We can do a somewhat "no-op" select to keep the TakeWhile separate from the working out of whether to keep going

So, we end up with:

```
bool foundCurrent = false;

var crumbs = cachedCrumbs.TakeWhile(crumb => !foundCurrent)
                         .Select(crumb => { 
                                 foundCurrent = crumb == null || !crumb.IsCurrent; 
                                 return crumb; });
```

I haven't tried this, but I *think* it should work... there might be a simpler way though.

EDIT: I'd argue that actually a straight foreach loop *is* simpler in this case. Having said that, you could write another extension method which acted like TakeWhile except it *also* returned the element which caused the condition to fail. Then it would be as simple as:

```
var crumbs = cachedCrumbs.NewMethod(crumb => crumb == null || !crumb.IsCurrent);
```

(I can't think of a decent name for the method at the moment, hence `NewMethod` !)

Comment: Hi Jon, this worked! Thank you. I understand what the select is doing, but I'm a little lost on the .TakeWhile(crumb => foundCurrent) - what exactly is that doing? And, why do we see foundCurrent again in the select?

Comment: The TakeWhile was actually wrong - it should have been "!foundCurrent" rather than "foundCurrent" - I've fixed it. The TakeWhile lambda is just "keep going while we haven't found current". The select lambda is basically to set foundCurrent *after* the TakeWhile.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, that code doesn't work.  I'm gonna guess that some of those places where you used "crumbs" you meant "cachedCrumbs".  If so, the code can be reduced to:

```
IList<Breadcrumb> crumbs = new List<Breadcrumb>();
for (int a = 0; a < cachedCrumbs.Count; a++)
{
    crumbs.Add(cachedCrumbs[a]);
    if (cachedCrumbs[a] != null && cachedCrumbs[a].IsCurrent)
    {
          break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi James. The code does work, I just tried to give a high level overview. I did not mean crumbs where I have cachedCrumbs. The cachedCrumbs is ALL of the possible crumbs, in order. Think of it like steps in a workflow, and not actual web breadcrumbs. Thx for tip on removing foundCurrent though!

Comment: No, you misread James' comment - your code had: "crumbs.Add(crumbs[a]);" where you actually meant "crumbs.Add(cachedCrumbs[a]);"

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer based on James Curran's - this can certainly be improved using a foreach statement:

```
IList<Breadcrumb> crumbs = new List<BreadCrumb>();
foreach (Breadcrumb crumb in cachedCrumbs)
{
    crumbs.Add(crumb);
    if (crumb != null && crumb.IsCurrent)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach loop doesn't guarantee that the crumbs are accessed in the order they actually appear.

Comment: They do for all sensible collections that support indexing by number. Can you think of a common IList implementation which misbehaves in this respect?

Comment: Thx for the foreach.. I had that first, but for some reason took it out. :) and this is the mess that was left afterwards. :)

Comment: I took it out because for some reason I thought I had to check the next crumb to determine if IsCurrent == true. That's why I removed the foreach. Which, turns out, isn't needed anymore, so I'll go back to foreach or the LINQ suggestion above.

Comment: Ah.. I can think of none... I mean it isn't guaranteed in the docs, is all.

Comment: I think it's assumed in *so* much code that any implementation which didn't abide by it would very rapidly get tossed aside.

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
// find the current item
var currentItem = cachedCrumbs.First(c => c.IsCurrent);
var currentIdx = cachedCrumbs.IndexOf(currentItem);

// get all items upto current item
var crumbs = cachedCrumbs.Take(currentIdx + 2);
```

And you can turn this into a TakeUpto method which takes all items upto the one which matched the predicates you supply.

How about:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeUpto<T>(this IList<T> theList, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var targetItem = theList.First(predicate);
    var targetIdx = theList.IndexOf(targetItem);

    return theList.Take(targetIdx + 2);
}
```

Then you could use it this way:

```
var crumbs = cachedCrumbs.TakeUpto(c => c.IsCurrent);
```

Much cleaner!

Havn't check the nulls and off-by-one cases and IList/IEnumerable differences, but you should get the idea.

Comment: Chakrit, I liked this solution alot and decided to use it. Thank you. :) I like the re-use candidacy of it.

Comment: Jon's solution can be refactored into an extension method that is as reusable... but it's a little complicated... I like more readability :-) but Jon's solution might execute faster though

Comment: Note that this solution relies on the ordering of the list's enumerator just as much as the foreach which you were critical of :)

Comment: (And yes, I think it's off by one - if it matches the first element, IndexOf will return 0, but you want to take one element.)

My main concern with this solution is that it iterates over the sequence 3 times. In *some* cases that will be expensive.

Comment: Just thought - as it can only work on ILists, it's less likely to be expensive than if it were dealing with IEnumerable. ILists don't tend to be lazily evaluated, but instead are fully in-memory. It wouldn't be impossible to have a lazy IList, admittedly... just unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is an alternative implementation of chakrit's TakeUpTo:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeUpto<T>(this IEnumerable<T> theList, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (T element in theList)
    {
        yield return element;
        if (predicate(element))
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This only iterates through the list once, which could be relevant in various cases. (Suppose the upstream sequence is the result of an OrderBy clause - you really don't want it to have to sort the results multiple times for no good reason.)

It also allows any `IEnumerable<T>` as the source, which makes it more flexible.

One of the wonderful things about LINQ is the multiple ways of achieving the same goal.