# How to calculate changes of nullable numbers with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I need to calculate changes off of time series of nullable numbers. The following code gets the job done:

```
public static double?[] GetChanges(double?[] x)
{
    if(x.Length == 1)
        throw new Exception("Time Series Too Short");
    var ret = new double?[x.Length - 1];
    for (int i = 1; i < x.Length; i++)
    {
        ret[i-1] = (x[i - 1].HasValue && x[i].HasValue) ? x[i] - x[i - 1] : null;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Is there a better way to accomplish that with Linq?
The library is using .Net 3.5.
Right now I cannot use Zip, because that comes with .Net 4.

Edit: following the advice by mquander and Eric Lippert, I have come up with the following code which runs on 3.5:

```
public class Tuple<T>
{
    public Tuple(T first)
    {
        First = first;
    }

    public T First { get; set; }
}

public class Tuple<T, T2> : Tuple<T>
{
    public Tuple(T first, T2 second)
        : base(first)
    {
        Second = second;
    }

    public T2 Second { get; set; }

    public static Tuple<T1, T2> New<T1, T2>(T1 t1, T2 t2)
    {
        return new Tuple<T1, T2>(t1, t2);
    }
}

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Pairs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq)
    {
        using (var enumerator = seq.GetEnumerator())
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            var prior = enumerator.Current;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return Tuple<T, T>.New(prior, enumerator.Current);
                prior = enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using this code as follows:

```
    public static IEnumerable<double?> GetChanges2(double?[] x)
    {
        if (x.Length == 1)
            throw new Exception("Time Series Too Short");
        return x.Pairs().Select(p => p.Second - p.First);
    }
```

Any suggestions on further improvement are welcome. 
I will be back when I have VS2010 and .Net 4, so that I can try out the approaches suggested in both answers.

Thanks!

Comment: I am confused by this code, specifically by the body of the loop. What purpose does the conditional operator achieve? Why is the body of the loop not simply "ret[i-1] = x[i]-x[i-1];" ???

Comment: Oh, I didn't personally know that you could subtract nullable numeric types and have it handle nulls correctly.  Awesome.

Comment: @mquander: yep, that's the whole point of nullable arithmetic. We automatically "lift" the operations to nullable. Where it breaks down, unfortunately, is in comparisons. In C#, when you compare a null double equal to another null double the result should be *null*. "null" means "I don't know", and the answer to "does one thing I don't know equal another thing I don't know" is not "true", is not "false", is "I don't know!" But comparisons always produce bools, not nullable bools. VB gets it right; in VB equality is three-valued.

Comment: @Eric: I did not know that x[i] - x[i - 1] already handles nulls for me. Nice tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another idea (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236676/can-this-be-refactored-into-nicey-nice-linq/236705#236705) answer) would be to keep the previous item in a captured variable:

```
static IEnumerable<double?> GetChanges(IEnumerable<double?> x)
{
    double? previous = x.First();
    return x.Skip(1).Select(d =>
              { double? result = d - previous; previous = d; return result; });
}
```

This must work because the captured variable is "hidden" in the function.

Comment: this thing does work on 3.5. IMO it is short and elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe just

```
Enumerable.Zip(
    x.Skip(1),
    x,
    (a, b) => (a.HasValue && b.HasValue) ? (a - b) : null)
)
```

?

By the way, I would use just doubles and [double.NaN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.nan.aspx) instead of nulls. This way the code can be simplified to just

```
Enumerable.Zip(x.Skip(1), x, (a, b) => a - b)
```

in this and perhaps some other places.

**EDIT:**
Following @Eric Lippert's advice, removing null checks is possible even for `Nullable` case. So the answer would be simply

```
Enumerable.Zip(x.Skip(1), x, (a, b) => a - b)
```

even in this case.

Comment: You probably want to reverse the `x.Skip(1)` and `x` arguments if you want to take this approach.

Comment: @Vlad: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx I need .Net 4 to use it. I am still on .Net 3.5. I know I should upgrade ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: The "hasvalues" are unnecessary regardless. Arithmetic on nullables is already lifted.

Comment: @Arne: You don't need to upgrade just for Zip. If you want the source code to Zip, it is very short. I've put the source code here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx

Comment: @Eric: thanks, didn't know about operations on nullables. This feature needs some advertizing :-)

Comment: @Vlad: OK, you got it. I'll go back in time a couple of weeks and have Bill Wagner write an article on that... and now back to the future again, and done. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/hh124568

Comment: @Eric: Thanks! I wish I could lend your time machine when I'm late with a deadline :-) But I don't see in the article anything about addition etc. -- maybe you could use the time machine once more?

Comment: @Eric: oh, I found that: the last 3 paragraphs.

Comment: @Vlad, I think it wasn't there when you looked for the first time, but Eric hopped into his DeLorean again and fixed it :-)

Comment: @Vlad: Hmm, you're right. I guess Bill didn't get to that bit. I'll mention it to him and maybe he can do a follow-up!

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  I would do it your way.  If you're feeling particularly functional, the way to go would be to define a `Pairs` method on `IEnumerable<T>` that breaks a sequence into a series of consecutive overlapping pairs, and then map each pair to the delta between its first and second value.

EDIT since an example was requested:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Pairs<T>(this IEnumerable<T> seq)
    {
        using (var enumerator = seq.GetEnumerator())
        {
            enumerator.MoveNext();
            var prior = enumerator.Current;

            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return Tuple.Create(prior, enumerator.Current);
                prior = enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then `GetChanges` is reduced to:

```
var changes = values.Pairs().Select(x => x.Item2 - x.Item1);
```

(Note that my implementation returns an empty sequence instead of throwing an exception if `values` contains less than two values.)

(edit again -- cleaned up the nullable type handling at the end, thanks Eric for pointing  it out!)

Comment: For posterity, the main reason I prefer this over Vlad's version using `Zip` is that Vlad enumerates the sequence twice, whereas you could properly write `Pairs` to only enumerate the sequence once.

Comment: @mquander: you are right, but I expect a really good optimizer to be able to cope with this. Not sure if the current C# versions are good enough.

Comment: @mquander: I am not following you (yet), can you give me a more detailed answer?

Comment: @Vlad: I would bet my life that no C# optimizer which will ever exist could manage that. It would have to know quite a lot about the implementation of both `Skip` and `Zip` to know that the optimization was correct, as well as knowing that enumerating this particular sequence has no side effects.

Comment: @mquander: looks like to run your example I need 4.0 release of Microsoft .NET Framework. I'll be back in a few days.

Comment: @Arne:  Sorry, `Tuple` requires 4.0.  To use my example on 3.5, you would unfortunately have to define your own tuple type (which is trivial in this case, at least.)

Comment: @mquander: actually some SQL optimizers are good enough already. So LINQ could overtake the same optimization logic.